# How to execute for loop between two numbers?

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to execute reverse for loop between two numbers.

```
for($m = 5 - 1; $m >= 0; $m--){

    echo $m . '<br />';
}
```

Output

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Now how can i get below out put

```
9
8
7
6
5
```

I would like to appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: **Really** You cannot just work that out for yourself? Or you can just play with it a bit till you get it right

Comment: `foreach(range($max, $min) as $m)`

Comment: There are correct answers below but you should just learn how a **for loop** works. It would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Is this the real life?

Comment: @Dave I wouldn't say its a dupe. $m-- is used with a valid condition for exiting the loop.

Answer (score -2):

how about +5 in the `echo`?

it maybe looks like:

```
echo $m + 5 . '<br />';
```